# How to suppress error message of autocmd command when the `silent` doesn't work?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-coc

I'm using Coc.vim and I've created [an issue on their GitHub](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/3029), but I'm not sure about whether this can be done by modifying the line I'm using:

```
autocmd CursorHold * silent call CocActionAsync('doHover')
```

as you can see I already added the `slient` above but it still show the error:

[image]

Then I will have to press enter since there are too many error message, which is annoying.

Comment: Read the help for `:silent` again. The answer is in the first few sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:h silent`:

> [...]
> When [!] is added, error messages will also be
> skipped, and commands and mappings will not be aborted
> when an error is detected. [...]

---

The problem can be solved by these two lines:

```
let blacklist = ['vim', 'help']
autocmd CursorHold * if (index(blacklist, &ft) < 0 || !coc#rpc#ready())
    \ | silent! call CocActionAsync('doHover')
```

Comment: Can I have the definition popup in NeoVim on mouse hover? That code shows it on mouse *click*.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich I don't know. But I just did a fuzzy-search for the word `mouse` in the `:h autocmd-events` section of Neovim, and found no match. So this is probably not supported in both Vim&Neovim currently. (since Neovim has more events than Vim.)